# How to use ProtectedPersonalData attribute

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-identity, .net-5

I found the attribute class, `ProtectedPersonalData` ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.protectedpersonaldataattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0)), of ASP.NET Core Identity framework, but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to use it.
The documentation only says: `Used to indicate that a something is considered personal data and should be protected.`

At the end, I was able to encrypt the Identity User class fields ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.entityframeworkcore.identityuser?view=aspnetcore-1.1)) (e.g. email field), but not any property of an Identity User inheriting class.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser {

        [ProtectedPersonalData]
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I added this to the Identity Config:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => {
                options.Stores.ProtectPersonalData = true;
            })
            .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

Moreover, I implemented protector classes:

```
public class Lookup : ILookupProtector {
            public string Protect(string keyId, string data) {
                return new string(data?.Reverse().ToArray());
            }

            public string Unprotect(string keyId, string data) {
                return new string(data?.Reverse().ToArray());
            }
        }

public class Protector : IPersonalDataProtector {
            public string Protect(string data) {
                return new string(data?.Reverse().ToArray());
            }

            public string Unprotect(string data) {
                return new string(data?.Reverse().ToArray());
            }
        }

public class KeyRing : ILookupProtectorKeyRing {
            public string this[string keyId] => "key";

            public string CurrentKeyId => "key";

            public IEnumerable<string> GetAllKeyIds() {
                return new string[] { "key" };
            }
        }
```

It is possible to encrypt `MyProperty` field?
Please point me to information or provide some examples please.

**Update:**

I noticed that the code is never entering inside the `Protect` method for property `MyProperty`.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetCoreIdentityEncryption

Comment: @NicolaBiada this is exactly what I followed, but I'm not understanding if I'm missing something!

Comment: I've tried in the past and the property goes through every method without any issues. Where do you have your issue?

Comment: Isn't working with the "MyProperty" inside the ApplicationUser that inherit from IdentityUser, while is working for the IdentityUser properties.

Comment: I give it a try right now. Nice question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add data annotation to the attribute qualifying as **PersonalData**, like this:

```
[ProtectedPersonalData]
[PersonalData]
public string Firstname { get; set; }

[ProtectedPersonalData]
[PersonalData]
public string Lastname { get; set; }
```

in order to *activate* the process you need register the services in your **Startup.cs**:

```
// ProtectedData
services.AddScoped<ILookupProtectorKeyRing, KeyRing>();
services.AddScoped<ILookupProtector, LookupProtector>();
services.AddScoped<IPersonalDataProtector, PersonalDataProtector>();
```

### Example Repository

Here you can find an example repository with a project Blazor WASM with Microsoft Identity accounts and **ProtectedData** implementation.

https://github.com/nbiada/protecteddata-wasm-example

Comment: I tried, but it's not working for me! I noticed that the code is never entering inside the Protect Method, for the property "MyProperty".

Comment: The code above, with the services registration, works very well. I've tested it on a Wasm app created from scratch. Try to create a new app and add only the essential parts.

Comment: Can you share it? Thank in advance!

Comment: Updated answer with an example repo

Comment: This attribute works also for another class (e.g. Product) ?

Comment: No, you can't with this technique, but you can add the AspNetCore.DataProtection library to your project and use direct _Protect_ / _Unprotect_, but is more useful for cookie or query strings. If you need to encrypt data on DB is better to use a native solution.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/blowdart/AspNetCoreIdentityEncryption